# Does "Binary Logarithm" means "Binary Number System" in Computer Science?

Tags: logarithms, computer-science, binary, number-systems

I am reading a paper, [NIST SP800-22 Revision 1a.](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation/documentation-and-software), about Randomness test in Computer system, which is from NIST, U.S. Department of Commerce.

## Question

**Does "Binary Logarithm" means "Binary Number System" in Computer Science?**

### Why I think

In that paper, 2.12.4 Test Description (Page 51), there is equation as below

---

$
(3) \ \ \ \mathrm{Compute} \  C_i^m = \frac{\sharp i}{n}
$

$
\mathrm{For \ the \ example \ in \ this \ section},\\\ C^3_{000} = 0, \ C^3_{001} = 0.1, \ C^3_{010} = 0.3, \ C^3_{011} = 0.1, \ C^3_{100} = 0.1, \ C^3_{101} = 0.3, \ C^3_{110} = 0.1, \ C^3_{111} = 0
$

$
(4) \ \ \ \psi^{(m)}=\displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{2^m-1} \pi_i log{\pi_i}, \ \mathrm{where} \  \pi_i=C^3_j, \ \mathrm{and} \  j=log_2i.
$

$
\mathrm{For \ the \ example \ in \ this \ section},\\\ \psi^{(3)} = 0(log \ 0)+0.1(log \ 0.1)+0.3(log \ 0.3)+0.1(log \ 0.1)+0.1(log \ 0.1)+0.3(log \ 0.3)+0.1(log \ 0.1)+0(log \ 0)=-1.64341772.
$

---

As you can see at Section (4), $j=log_2i$.

Why $\pi_3 = C^3_{log_23}=C_{011}^3$ ? Then, does "Binary Logarithm" means "Binary Number System" in Computing?

- Link [Project : Random Bit Generation](https://csrc.nist.gov/projects/random-bit-generation/documentation-and-software)
- Link [Final Documentation](https://csrc.nist.gov/publications/detail/sp/800-22/rev-1a/final) Page 51-52

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, 'binary logarithm' does not mean 'binary number system'; it just means 'logarithm with base 2'.

Purely based on your description, it looks as if the authors of the paper made a mistake and simply meant '$j$ is the binary representation of $i$' instead of '$j = \log_2 i$'.

Comment: Thank you. Then This is just misprint.. :(